# WildFly 10.0.0.Final jboss-modules.jar does not exist

Tags: jboss, angular, wildfly

I have tried for several hours now trying to setup a WildFly Server to start. I am currently using Eclipse Mars and Mac El Capitan. The following error I get is: `The archive: /Servers/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or have some suggestions? I have tried tutorials for setup and have had zero luck.

I was using Tomcat before for my side projects but now Since Angular 2 I was suggested to use WildFly for the conversion of typescript to javascript.

Comment: Does the file `/Servers/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar` exist? maybe your download was corrupted or the server path is wrong !!

Comment: I am sorry I should have specified that, yes the .jar file exists. This is the server runtime path /Users/csexton/Eclipse Workspace/Servers/wildfly-10.0.0.Final    should I specify the .jar file specifically in the runtime environment path? or could it be the space between Eclipse Workspace?

Comment: Sorry I don't use eclipse, but the space could be an issue, try renaming the `Eclipse Workspace` to something like `Eclipse_Workspace`. Specially that the error message is showing an incorrect path.

Comment: Also, check the `-Djboss.home.dir` cli argument, it should point to `"/Users/csexton/Eclipse Workspace/Servers/wildfly-10.0.0.Final"`

Comment: I had to change the $JBOSS_HOME environment variable to the correct path. It was pointing to the wrong directory. Thank You.....